# Testing Inversify w/ Mocha causes strange error ERROR_MSGS.NULL_ARGUMENT

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js, inversifyjs

I'm getting the following error when I try to test my code with Mocha/Chai.
Has anyone else seen this error?

```
/Users/me/Sites/my_project/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/lookup.js:13
            throw new Error(ERROR_MSGS.NULL_ARGUMENT);
            ^

Error: NULL argument
    at Lookup.add (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/lookup.js:13:19)
    at Container.bind (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:121:33)
    at Object. (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/test/api-temp/dependency-injection.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object. (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/test/api-temp/services/some.service.js:21:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object. (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/test/api-temp/services/some.service.spec.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /Users/me/Sites/my_project/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/me/Sites/my_project/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:487:10)
    at Object. (/Users/me/Sites/facecards-api/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:459:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

npm ERR! Darwin 16.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/me/.nvm/v4.4.5/bin/node" "/Users/dan/.nvm/v4.4.5/bin/npm" "run" "test-api" "-w"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my_project@1.0.0 test-api: `mocha -R spec './test/api-temp/**/*.spec.js' --reporter min --inline-diffs`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

The problem occurs when I try to new up the class in my test code.

```
describe('SomeService', () => {

    let someService: any

    someService = new SomeService(null, null, null)
    mockFunction = sinon.createStubInstance(someService, 'function')

     describe('#function', () => {

         beforeEach(() => {
             result = someService.function(1234)
         })

         it('should call function', () => {
             expect(.callCount).to.eql(1)
         })
     })

})
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of SomeService and all the imports? I don't think I have enough information to help at this point. Can you please also post the version of node, typescript and inversify? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using: 

node v6.10.1
inversify 3.3.0
typescript 2.2.2

Comment: I'm getting the imports and everything together.. I'll post a link here in a bit.

Comment: @DanielDavidson - i am getting a similar error, did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get through it... I believe it was the Node version I was using.  But, I also noticed that my assertion for the above code is not correct.

`it('should call function', () => {
     expect(.callCount).to.eql(1)
 })`

needs to reference the function I'm trying to test...  
`function.callCount`

Comment: Having the same issue. Basically I'm trying to instantiate a class like this:

        let mqttService = inversifyContainer.get<MqttService>(MqttService);

if I add the same line in the first test parsed by mocha (everywhere, i.e. in the before() method, the error goes away.

The strange thing is that the error goes away even if I .skip() completely the test, it seems that mocha is parsing anyway the test and for some reason instantating the class somewhere is fixing the issue.

I have no idea why

Comment: I was able to get around everything by using an updated version of node.  >6.3.0 seemed to work for me.

Comment: We found that this is sometimes caused by a circular dependency.